# JSON.NET Deserialize on non-binary tree

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, json-deserialization

Guys I want to have a posibility to deserializing JSON to non-binary tree.

For example, I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "entry1":[
    {
      "entry2":[
        {
          "entry3":[
            {
              "elements":[
                {
                  "name":"element1"
                },
                {
                  "name":"element2"
                },
                {
                  "name":"element3"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And as result I want to have a recursive remove function. For example: I want to remove some element with specific name, and then if elements list is empty need to remove all branch/node.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a function in `json.net`. You would have to write your own remove function that does this. So, after deleting an element you can check if the parent as any children, if not, delete it as well and so on until you reached the root element.